# Установка socket.io,node,laravel

Tags: сокет

После установки сокетов `npm install --save socket.io --msvs_version=2013`,"падает" сборка `npm run dev`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл сборки:

```
mix.scripts([
    'resources/assets/plugins/jquery.min.js',
    'resources/assets/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js',
    'resources/assets/plugins/jquery.mask.js',
    'resources/assets/plugins/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.js',
    'resources/assets/js/socket.js'
], 'public/js/vendors.min.js');
mix.scripts([
   'resources/assets/js/ajax.js',
   'resources/assets/js/main.js',
   'resources/assets/js/profile.js',
   'resources/assets/js/register.js'
], 'public/js/app.min.js');

mix.js('public/js/vendors.min.js', 'public/js/vendors.min.js')

"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.3",
    "debug": "^2.6.8",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "ioredis": "^3.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^0.8.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.3",
    "vue": "^2.1.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bufferutil": "^3.0.1",
    "debug": "^2.6.8",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "hiredis": "^0.5.0",
    "ioredis": "^3.1.1",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "tls": "0.0.1",
    "utf-8-validate": "^3.0.2"
```

Подскажите куда копать чтобы ее исправить. Может путь к файлам нужно иначе задавать? Спасибо

Comment: да,но физически эти файлы на месте

Answer (score 0):

Поменял настройки в `webpack.config.js`

```
    var webpack = require('webpack');
    var path = require('path');
    var fs = require('fs');

    var nodeModules = {};
    fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
      .filter(function(x) {
        return ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1;
      })
      .forEach(function(mod) {
        nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
      });

    module.exports = {
      entry: './src/main.js',
      target: 'node',
      output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'backend.js'
      },
      externals: nodeModules
    }
```